# Ajax GET/POST Django, not really sure what to do with data

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

Im trying to perform a query on a page with AJAX. Backend is using Django. My javascript is like so:

```
$(function(){
    $("#form").submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var query = ($("#input-field").val());
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url:"{% url 'search_building' %}",
            data: {
                'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}',
                'q': query
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $("#search-results").html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The whole page is coming through and appending #search-results, where as I just want the results to come through from a table.

Im also a little confused about whether I should use a GET or POST with Ajax, and whether I should be using csrf token.

Much appreciated.

---

I figured it out!

My original page used one view, one url, and a template that returned all results from a query

I wanted to use Django's templating language, so I didnt want the output to be in json and then to write javascript to handle the output.

So I created a second template to render just my results, a view to handle the query and then used ajax to handle sending the query to new view and render the results from the new template into the old one.

Comment: `Im also a little confused about whether I should use a GET or POST with Ajax, and whether I should be using csrf token.` That would all depend on what the endpoint you're calling requires.

Comment: I'm not sure what confuses you. If you're sending data to update your database, use POST; if you're requesting data to update the page, use GET. And if you just want the contents of the table to be sent, you should write your view to only send that part.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman Id read a couple of times (and seen a couple of examples) that it was recommended to use POST with ajax and a csrf token even when getting data.

Comment: Wherever you read that, it is wrong. HTTP semantics are the same whether you're using Ajax or not.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman Thanks! Will stick to that then

Answer (score 0):

Try to return the response from the backend in json format.
That would make it very easy to use the response data and you can use it however you like.

The reason behind whole page loading is because you are rendering a template, with a context.

For an ajax request, response in json format is preferrable for the data handling.

Also, if you wish to write into database, such as new instance, something like that, use POST request.
Instead all that you need is to call an api for some query or situations where you expect the api to provide data, you can use GET request.

This is all my version of what I've learned.
Hope you got what you asked.!

Comment: @ Fazil Bin Zaid Thanks for the help! Would you recommend writing a view that handles both the template and json with is_ajax()?

Comment: I figured it out! I prefer to use the Django templating language, so its best if the response came as html, instead of writing out a whole bunch of javascript for a json response. I created a new view to generate the response and a template to handle the results, then used ajax to replace the results on the main page.